# Add the [amazon-eks] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

Currently, there is no tag for Amazon's EKS service.

I recommend [amazon-eks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-eks) since it follows the same naming convention as a similar tag for Amazon ECS, [amazon-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ecs).

> Amazon Elastic Container Service for Kubernetes (Amazon EKS) makes it
> easy to deploy, manage, and scale containerized applications using
> Kubernetes on AWS.
>
> Amazon EKS runs the Kubernetes management infrastructure for you
> across multiple AWS availability zones to eliminate a single point of
> failure. Amazon EKS is certified Kubernetes conformant so you can use
> existing tooling and plugins from partners and the Kubernetes
> community. Applications running on any standard Kubernetes environment
> are fully compatible and can be easily migrated to Amazon EKS.
>
> Amazon EKS is generally available for all AWS customers.

Existing questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775942/iam-permission-management-on-amazon-eks
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914642/how-do-i-specify-which-availability-zone-my-eks-cluster-will-be-deployed-to

Comment: Are there any questions about Amazon EKS out there yet?

Comment: I've asked 2 now...

Comment: @Makoto I've added the two questions I could find.

Comment: @AndrewRoth It's generally appreciated that you add links to existing questions, when asking for a new tag ;)

Comment: @Stijn Thanks, this is the first time I've done a tag request. Looks like an edit has already been proposed that adds 2 questions. I can go ahead and propose another edit to add the one I just asked as well

Comment: Are questions about setting up Kubernetes in AWS on-topic? Kubernetes itself is barely on-topic. Do these belong on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com)?

Answer (score 9):

Okay.  I can see this being a viable thing.  I've created the tag ([amazon-eks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-eks)) and edited one of your questions to remove the note about the tag not existing.

I leave it to others to fill out an appropriate tag wiki and blurb about it (which doesn't just copy verbatim from the Amazon EKS site).